# Why do professors cut communication with their employees once their contract ends, even with on-going projects/articles?

Tags: phd, postdocs

I have noticed this behaviour several times with many people. Once the contract of employees (such as PhDs, Postdocs, ...) ends, Professors/employers cut the communication with them even if projects or articles are still going on.

Those PhDs or Postdocs then need to finish the project/papers on their own, in a kind of isolation, i.e. with no or very limited scientific support and feedback from their previous employers.

Therefore, I do not understand the reasons why Professors/employers reduce drastically the communication and scientific discussions with their ex-employees about works that, sooner or later, will be published with their names over.

I mean, at the end, the articles that will be published by ex-PhDs or ex-Postdocs will be additional papers also for Professors/employers. So, why this lack of communication (and interest?) by Professors/employers towards ex-employees who will work for free to finish the articles?

Comment: Can you please clarify waht the last sentence is supposed to mean? I tried to understand what you wanted to say, but wasn't able to.

Comment: @Sursula-they- thanks for your comment, I have amended the text... Hope it is clearer

Comment: I’ve not experienced that. However, out of sight out of mind has some credibility.

Comment: You present this as a general problem. I doubt, seriously, that it is. Unless someone is too busy to keep up the same level of communication there doesn't seem to be any advantage in it.

Comment: When I went from undergrad to grad school it was definitely the opposite for me - advisor kept in contact, and I was hard to get ahold of. I don't think this is a general phenomenon at all.

Answer (score 4):

This is not common. Some professors may be too busy to respond to their previous employees or may be they like isolation. But in most cases, they remain in touch with the employee until the project is over.

I know some people have very bad experiences with their professors but these are very few.